# Using underscore with jshint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I'm using the underscore library.

I get this when running jshint:

```
[L38:C38] W117: '_' is not defined.
      var approvedAndRequstedCount = _.countBy(products, function(obj) {
```

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

This is my config file:

```
{
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "camelcase": false,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 2,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "quotmark": "single",
  "regexp": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "strict": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "smarttabs": true,
  "globals": {
    "angular": false
  }
}
```

I guess it's something with the globals option? I tried to add "_": false but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `"_": false` works for me (in globals).

Comment: Oh! Yes, I also have a `"-W117": true` on the main configuration object.

Comment: W117: true solved the issue! Thx. I'll approve if you post an answer with a short explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure turning off W117 is a _good_ thing.  But it is a workaround.  Probably not good enough for an answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had this issue as well.

I installed underscore: `bower install -save underscore` and it worked fine in the code.  Unfortunately jshint was not finding that reference. You must tell jshint about your global variables in configuration file [like .jshintrc](http://jshint.com/docs/):

```
{
  …
  "globals": {
    "angular": false,
    "_": false
  }
}
```

If you continue to have this issue you need to make sure that underscore is included when jshint is executed.  I would *not* recommend setting -W117 to true.  Squelching those errors might lead to more bugs.

Comment: This also applies when using lodash. It worked for me.